# How do I print the amount of character's in an LC3/assembly code program

Tags: lc3

Basically my code will have me enter some text then it will print back what I entered. As it stands the code when I am entering text is weird symbols but prints what I actually type. Apart from that I want to know how to make my program print how many characters are being entered and display that number back(output)

```
.orig   x3000
Lea r1, storeString

Lea r0, PrintStudent
puts

Lea r0, EnterText
puts

LOOP
getc

str r0, r1, 0
add r1, r1, 1
add r0, r0, -10

brz OUTSIDE
out

brnzp LOOP

OUTSIDE

Lea r0, UserEnter
puts

Lea r0, storeString
puts

Halt
PrintStudent .stringz "Hi it's me"
EnterText .stringz "\nPlease enter a text: "
UserEnter .stringz "\nThe text you have typed is: "
storeString .blkw 99

.end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's why it's storing right but printing wrong:

```
GETC          # r0: new character
STR r0,r1,0   # r0: new character, mem[r1]: new character
ADD r1,r1,1   # increments pointer for storage
ADD r0,r0,-10 # r0: new character - newline, i.e. "a"--> "W"
OUT           # prints the input character - newline
```

Basically, move that "out" above the decrement and branch and you're in business (except that it will print the newline now too).

To know how many characters you've taken, you could count separately in the input loop, or you could calculate the difference between r1 and the address of storeString at the end of the loop.  Several other options exist as well: You're the design engineer.